# Windows store applications - Front-end in HTML5 and Back-end in C#/C++

Tags: c#, .net, html, windows-store-apps, windows-store

How can I build Windows Store application which Front-end is in HTML5 and Back-end in C#/C++ (such as Skype)? If I want to build Windows Store application in C# or C++, Visual Studio automatically generates MainPage.xaml. Is it possible to replace MainPage.xaml for HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to write [Windows Runtime components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441572.aspx) in C# or C++ which can be called by Windows Store HTML/JS application.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, the code behind in C#, like a HTML5 / Windows Store version of ASP.NET, I don't think that's possible. You can insert some HTML elements into a XAML UI using the WebBrowser control, but as far as I know that's the best you can do.

You could have a separate C# based web service, with which the HTML5 app communicates, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Windows 8 application using HTML/JavaScript. Refer to the link below for a help guide and more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx

Dont think there is a way to use HTML and C#